# not operator in perl doesnt give same results for two codes

Tags: perl

I am testing two perl codes with not operator but looks like its giving two different results i.e.

```
$a = 1;

print "the value of a is $a\n";

$a = $a - 1;
$b = not $a;

print "value of b is $b\n";
```

When I run the above code, I get

```
the value of a is 1
value of b is 1
```

but when i modify the above code to following

```
$a = 1;

print "the value of a is $a\n";

#$a = $a - 1;
$b = not $a--;

print "value of b is $b\n";
```

i get following result

```
the value of a is 1
value of b is
```

shouldn't `not($a)` in first code same as `not($a--)` in second code?

Answer (score 3):

`$a--` says decrement `$a` but return the value *before* decrementing.  To have the code work the same you want `--$a`.

For more information read: [perlop - Auto-increment and Auto-decrement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement)